# What does "Land Effect" actually affect?

Tags: shining-force

While playing [Shining Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shining_Force) one of the boxes that is always on the upper left of the screen during combat is the "Land Effect" percentage:

[image: Land Effect at 30%]

This is apparently an important variable, but I haven't been able to find a good explanation of it's effects. Does it affect only defense, or are speed and offense also influenced? Does it affect different unit types differently?

So basically, **what, if anything, does Land Effect do**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically this acts as cover - units take reduced damage proportional to the Land Effect of the tile they're standing on.  So in this eaxmple, Luke would be taking 30% less damage from attacks.

It's possibly worth noting that this is independent from the movement distance reduction that you get from heavy terrain, but typically high land effect terrain also slows your movement.

Comment: I've up voted you as I feel your answer is superior. Not only because you associate the concept of "cover" which most accurately describes the mechanic, but more importantly because the accepted answer is wrong by associating reduced movement. I've edited the accepted answer for Truth.

Answer (score 3):

Land Effect reduces the damage that you will take in combat.

In your example, if you were going to take 10 damage, you would only receive 7 instead. This only affects units that are on the ground.

It also affects your movement capabilities, but it almost never factors in unless the value is greater than 50% and it will knock off a movement square from your character if it moves through these "Land Effect" areas.